# Stackoverflow, check your privilege!

Tags: support, status-bydesign, comments, notifications, privileges

Saw this notification in my list, went to comment, and was informed I didn't yet have enough rep.

[image: Inaccurate privilege notification]

Is it possible to lose reputation and therefore lose privileges on stackoverflow? (I don't remember ever hitting 50 in the first place, and my rep earned prior to that doesn't add up to 50 anyhow.)

I can't think of another good explanation other than a coding error or notification code that wasn't updated when privilege levels were changed. (I haven't been around here long enough to know -- though that should be self evident, heh.)

Comment: You probably got an upvote that got removed - bringing you over the reputation threshold for a bit. During that time **you did have the privilege**, but lost it soon after.

Comment: What about a _"Sorry, but you've lost a privilege – comment everywhere – learn more"_ then?

Comment: Alright. So does someone want to answer the question to the effect of "it's by design"? Or shall I do it myself? What's the protocol here?

Comment: As pointed out, there is a suitable duplicate question, so we simply mark this question as a duplicate. I've also tagged this [status-bydesign] for the sake of completeness.